# libgdx touchdown not triggering until touchup or touchmove

Tags: java, windows, libgdx

I'm using libGDX on Windows 10/7 touchscreens. I'm trying to listen for the moment a user's finger touches the screen. I have tried both the touchDown event and reading isTouched in the render loop.

```
public void render(float delta) {
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
      this.screenInput();
    }
    game.batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    game.batch.end();
}
```

and

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter () {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        return screenInput();
    }
});
```

I even tried listening for changes in Gdx.input.getX(). All of these approaches will trigger, *but only if I lift or move my finger.* As in *touchDown*, *isTouched* or changes in *getX* only seem to occur when I lift or move my finger, not on the initial press. As long as I hold my finger still on the screen after a press I don't get anything.

I'm beginning to suspect this is an OS level problem I'm having. If I can make an adjustment to the touch settings on Windows to fix this, it would also be acceptable.

Even if I'm not doing anything obviously wrong, I'd like to know if anyone has experience with touchDown not triggering on first press or if it does indeed trigger on first touch for you, just so that I know if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I suspect it is the OS. LibGDX is relying on click events from the JVM. Windows may only be registering a click after a complete yap and release.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the return? Try just printing something out to console and then return false.

Comment: I've tried returning both true and false from screenInput, as well as just printing and replacing the call altogether with either boolean, but no luck. I suspect what Tenfour04 says is correct, but the similar "touchstart" event registers just fine in *JavaScript* tested in the browser (tested here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml), and it seems odd that Java's touchDown wouldn't be triggered by the same OS event. If Java relies on the JVM making all touches into clicks that would explain things, but be unfortunate.